# React Navigation 3 Top Tabs

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation 3, I want the hide the header and display my custom header that contains the tabs as the following picture.[image]

```
const HomeTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Tab1: InviHistory,
  Tab2: Shop
},{
  tabBarOptions: {
    scrollEnabled: true,
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this.

```
 defaultNavigationOptions:{
    headerMode:"none"
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, am i making a mistake with the brackets ?

Comment: ahh I misunderstand to question. I guess  TabNav dont have  ```defaultNavigationOptions```. so you want  to hide tab-nav standart header ? or upper Views written "Offers" ?

Comment: can i add my custom header as the above image ?

Comment: do you want to achive something like this ? https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/frowning-chips

Comment: yeah, but how can i add the tabs inside the header ?

Comment: You can add any component as your header with react navigation.

Comment: how can i do that ? i have my component ready but how can i add the the tabs inside it ?

Comment: did you checked  snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/frowning-chips ?

Comment: Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answear to Your question is in react-navigation docs.

```
class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={require('./spiro.png')}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
      />
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        // headerTitle instead of title
        headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
    };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```

With param `header` you can pass component to replace header at all.

Navigation Options API: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator

Configuring header API: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html